# changing the back ground color of an Excel chart in C#

Tags: c#, excel, ole

I'm working on creating an Excel Chart from my C# application that pulls data out of my SQL Server database, and using that data, creates some Charts in an Excel instance.  I have a pie chart that displays with the data, and all is well, accept I want to change the background color of the ChartArea and maybe use a gradient to add a little visual variation.  I'm having trouble figuring out how do do that in C# using OLE.  It looks like Office 16 is installed.  This should be simple, but I'm having trouble with this.  I saw a chart.ChartArea.Fill.BackColor property, but it's read only (I can't set it).  Not sure how to do this programmatically. Any ideas would be helpful.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find an answer after more searching.  It was the ForeColor property that I wanted after all.  The following line of code worked:

```
myChart.ChartArea.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.SomeColor);
```